# Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb.jsc) failed

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm newbie in `cocos2d-x` 
After creating `javascript` project with `create_project.py` command line and run the project, I see these warnings in the console:

```
Cocos2d: Get data from file(cocos2d-jsb.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_cocos2d_constants.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_cocos2d.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_cocos2d_extension.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_cocos2d_studio.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_chipmunk_constants.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_chipmunk.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_opengl_constants.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_opengl.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_cocosbuilder.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_sys.jsc) failed!
Cocos2d: Get data from file(jsb_deprecated.jsc) failed!
```

There are no `.jsc` file in my project, it only has `.js` file instead. 
 
1. How can I get rid of those warnings> 
2. Are there any recommended document for beginner about cocos2d javascripts? 
 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It first looks for .jsc files as its compiled javascript and probably faster, if it cant find them, it falls back to using .js files.. Thats the usual behavior,

Refer jsbcore.mm for cocos2d-iphone and ScriptingCore.cpp in Cocos2d-x

also,
If you are newly creating the project, it will check if there are any jsc files, if not it will create them for you if a flag is set ( JSB_ENABLE_JSC_AUTOGENERATION for cocos2d-iphone)

These warnings are thrown by FileUtils, so there is nothing to worry about it..

Comment: thanks. 
And about the second question: any idea?
2. Are there any recommended document for beginner about cocos2d javascripts?